# Creating new objects in Python with different methods

Tags: python, sorting, object

If you use the `sorted()` method on a variable does it create a new object?

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) (to be exact, it creates a shallow copy)

Comment: Yep. If you have `a` and do `sorted(a)`, you still have `a` in memory unchanged

Comment: This question is extremely low effort. Please at least attempt to use Google before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply yes, see also the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

> A simple ascending sort is very easy: just call the sorted() function. It returns a new sorted list

```
>>> sorted([5, 2, 3, 1, 4])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can also try it yourself:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(a) is a
False
```